# NAN when dividing 0 by 0

Tags: php

I made a Poll Voting with an Result Page. But wenn there are no votes it gives me an NAN Calc Error.

Code:

```
<div class="progress-bar" style="background-color: #38b673; width:<?= @(($poll_answer['votes'] / $total_votes) * 100)?>%">
<?= @round(($poll_answer['votes'] / $total_votes) * 100) ?>%
</div>
```

I tried different things, but nothing works.

Maybe anyone knows how to fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use `max()` function to overcome divide by 0 issue.

```
<?php echo round(($poll_answer['votes'] / max(1,$total_votes)) * 100); ?>
```

Comment: This is brilliant! Now I’m debating on using this technique over PHP’s newer intdiv() or fdiv() functions, which also handle divide by zero’s elegantly.

Comment: @FredTheWebGuy Haha, good to know. Appreciate the feedback.